# Variable pre-fixes, Visual Studio 2010 onwards?

Tags: .net, coding-style, naming-conventions

I'm a bit bewildered on this subject, as I relate variable prefixes to being a thing of the past now, but with Visual Studio 2010 onwards (I'm currently using 2012), do people still do this and why?

I only ask because, these days, you can hover over any variable and it'll tell you the variable type and scope. There's literally no requirement for pre-fixing being there for readability.

By this I mean:

```
string strHello
int intHello
```

etc.

And I'm being language/tool biased here - as Visual Studio takes a lot of the legwork out for you in terms of seeing exactly what type the variable is, including after conversions in the code. This is not a "general programming" question.

Comment: I *think* you are referring to variable prefixes that denote types on simple variables such as integers and strings. Please clarify that in your question, as there are other kinds of prefixes (e.g. for control types in GUI programming) that require separate thoughts.

Comment: Apologies, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3):

The significant point is that the variable name "should not" represent its type. Instead, It should indicate the "business semantic" of the variable; The type of the variable is subject to change during the code maintenance, but the semantics of that variable is rarely changed.

Incorporating "[StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)" into your development lifecycle can enforce consistent code style amongst team members.

**UPDATE**:
This excerpt from the Chapter 3 of "[Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756)" which is dedicated to "Naming Guidelines" helps to clarify the issue:

> Identifier names should clearly state what each member does and what
>   each type and parameter represents. To this end, it is more important
>   that name be clear than that it be short. Names should correspond to
>   scenarios , logical or physical parts of the system, and well-known
>   concepts rather than to technologies or architecture.
>
> DO choose easily readable identifier names.[...]
>
> DO favor readability over brevity.[...]
>
> DO NOT use underscores, hyphens, or any other non-alphanumeric
>   characters.[...]
>
> DO NOT use Hungrian Notation. [...]

Comment: Can you give an example of this please, a variable with a "business semantic" ?

Comment: Point here is, a variable name should identify its contents, not itself. If you put a person's name in a string variable, it shouldn't be called "strPersonName" but simply "PersonName".

Comment: Aha, this makes sense and is what I do currently, thank you for explaining the reasoning in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

We don't do Hungarian notation anymore, but when I'm programming GUI-stuff, I tend to pre- or postfix controls. e.g. `lblName` or `nameLabel`, `tfName` of `nameTextField`.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing variable names with an indication of their type is called Hungarian notation (e.g. strName).  It was often done wrong in the past and is usually discouraged these days.

Comment: "Systems Hungarian"; apps is still useful/used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), yes, it's a thing of the past and it's no longer recommended by anyone (that I know of). See [MSDN naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

However, many people like to add a prefix to field names, to differentiate them from local variables and parameters. I personally prefix field names with "_".

Comment: "Systems Hungarian"; apps is still useful/used, which is covered in the Wiki article.